# Page's HTML code written into file when file is downloaded from web app

Tags: java, download

I have a downloadfile servlet code that will dynamically add contents into a CSV file for users to download. However instead of having the contents I want added into the CSV file, the page's HTML code appears in the file instead. Can anyone tell me what is causing this bug? Here's my controller code

```java
response.setContentType("text/csv");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment"; 
filename="\\evaluations.csv\\");

try
{
    OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    String outputResult = "xxxx, yyyy, zzzz, aaaa, bbbb, ccccc, dddd, eeee, ffff, gggg\n";
    outputStream.write(outputResult.getBytes());
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
} catch(Exception e) {
    status = "Error exporting file, please try again later";
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
        
//request.setAttribute("status",status);
//dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/viewEvaluations.jsp");
//dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

EDIT:

Removing the forward request actually stop the HTML code from being copied into the file and I also realized its redundant and I've commented them out. This was the code that was causing the problem.

Comment: Why your are forwarding the request to another jsp?

Comment: Why are you doing `dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/viewEvaluations.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);` ?

Comment: its meant to refresh the page after the file is downloaded, could this be the one causing the error?

Comment: @ClementOng Yes, by using `outputStream.write` you already written on response stream and then you again telling `dispatcher` to forward the request.

Comment: okay, removing the forward request actually worked and the html code no longer appears. I realise that portion is redundant too. However, I still am not able to see the content i inserted

Comment: @ClementOng means you want to refresh the page after user clicks on hyperlink and download the file also or just you want to show a div which is hidden on page load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you just want to reload the current page then you can do a trick:

Your `<a>` tag should be like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="test">Click Here</a>
```

In Jquery:

```
$('#test').click(function() 
{   
    location.href='download'; //your download request mapping
    setTimeout(function(){location.reload()},2000); //this will reload the current page after 2 seconds.
});
```

Your controller code will be:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void download(Locale locale, Model model,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,HttpSession session) {
        response.setContentType("text/csv");
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=evaluations.csv");

        try
        {
            OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
            String outputResult = "xxxx, yyyy, zzzz, aaaa, bbbb, ccccc, dddd, eeee, ffff, gggg\n";
            outputStream.write(outputResult.getBytes());
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {

           //logging
        }
    }
```

If you want to make visible an div which is hidden on page load then rather than calling `location.reload()` u should call `$('#divId').show()`